# How do I make free body diagram for beam at an angle?

Tags: classical-mechanics, free-body-diagram

In my class materials I've came to this issue twice. The first time I thought *they* solved it wrong, but now that I see a similar situation again I'm more keen on the thought that I'm misunderstanding mechanics.
Here's a picture:

[image]

So to solve what I need to solve, I need to first figure out the **force** that is acting **vertically down** on the surface I painted in blue. But here's the **problem**

[image]

On which leg do I put the force F=6kN? To my logic, the second case should be correct, because the beam is transferring the force that I am investing. I was very **surprised** when I saw that they solved it the **first way**. Because now, the force that the beam is transferring (the *diagonal* one) is **larger** than the force I invested. Which I don't think makes sense. So which is the correct way to solve this, and if it is the *first* way, how does it make any sense?

Comment: #5 is a two force member and it can only carry tension on compression along its axis. But the tension _is not_ equal to the applied load $F$ due to the angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's the horizontal force.

First note that Force is not conserved, work (energy) is.

$$ Work=Force \times Distance$$

(e.g. If a car brakes from 30 to zero in 10seconds the forces are low. If it hits a wall at 30 they are high. The energy change is the same.)

Second, if the limbs of the machine are suitably constrained it transfers all of it's force into tension in the rod, and into the downward direction in leg3.
(imagine driving the top of a wheel with a horizontal force, the side of the wheel would experience the same force vertically. Or imagine a hydraulic system, which hydraulic pressure allows to be omnidirectional)

(It's not clear from the diagram that the limb with diameter m is constrained - but that seems likely.)

Generally speaking for increasing/decreasing forces in mechanical machines look for levers (with a pivot) or gearing (with gear wheels of different diameters).

Answer (score 0):

The force $F=6 {\rm kN}$ acts horizontally. So if the tension/compression on #5 is $T$ the following equation balances the forces in the horizontal direction

$$ T \cos \varphi = F $$

The corresponds the the figure on left left. Some of the tensions goes towards the reaction force at #6. Specifically $T \sin \varphi = R$. If the angle was zero, then there would be no reaction force.

Comment: Well how isn't this leaning towards some sort of perpetum mobile then?
I'm giving in 6kN, and I'm getting 6/cos(22) = 6.45kN

Comment: The torque transmitted is $\tau = L\, T \cos\varphi = L\, F$. The increase in tension is taken out when the force is transmitted to the rest of the system.

Answer (score 0):

It is the first way, as the class materials indicate.   You provide the horizontal force on the piston, and the upper part of the piston cylinder provides the downward vertical force on the piston.    Yes, those component forces add up to a greater force than you apply, but that shouldn't bother us--this is often the case in machines.    Think of simple machines like the lever or the wedge.   *Work* cannot be multiplied by machines, but force can be.

And the force diagram shown for the beam is incomplete.   The full diagram would show balancing forces up and to the right, provided by #4.